# Can't see why onActivityResult isn't working

Tags: android, android-intent

The "setResult" on the second activity either isn't passing the data back to the onActivityResult in the first, or onActivityResult isn't even being called... I can't figure out which

---

First Activity:

```
//-- Handle item selection
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Options.class);
            Bundle counters = new Bundle();
            counters.putInt("plWin", plWin);
            counters.putInt("plLoss", plLoss);
            counters.putInt("plDraw", plDraw);
            i.putExtras(counters);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_reset:




//-- Data being passed from "Options" --
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){
    Bundle counts = i.getExtras();
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BOOM SHAKA LAKA!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        plWin = counts.getInt("Win", 100);
        plLoss = counts.getInt("Loss", 100);
        plDraw = counts.getInt("Draw", 100);
    }
}
}
```

---

Second Activity:

```
}
//-- Data being passed back to "Main" -- 
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle counters = new Bundle();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    counters.putInt("Win", wins);
    counters.putInt("Loss", losses);
    counters.putInt("Draw", draws);
    i.putExtras(counters);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this

```
plWin=data.getIntExtra("Win",0);
plLoss=data.getIntExtra("Loss",0);
plDraw=data.getIntExtra("Draw",0);
```

and check the values if they are returning zero it means there is some problem passing passing the extra or Bundle from activity.

If is there any condition like that handle that by code but as i think these function will not through any exception.

Comment: no exceptions...  I'm getting the feeling that it's not calling them at all.  I did that but instead of '0' I used '100' and didn't get either one

Comment: to back-up my previous statement.  I inserted a toast right under the onActivityResult if method and it's not activating

Comment: as requested by AlexN, I've changed the op... pasted the entirety of both activites

Comment: @WizardKnight accept the answer if your problem is solved that i posted recently with full coe it will help other too.

Answer (score 1):

Change code to:

```
Bundle counts = data.getExtras();
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
    plWin = counts.getInt("Win");
    plLoss = counts.getInt("Loss");
    plDraw = counts.getInt("Draw");
}
```

getIntent() in your case returned the intent with which the first activity was started. Caller activity, so nothing about returning data from second activity.

UPD:
Also I want to highlight that `onBackPressed()` in second activity is implemented very strange. It's calling `super.onBackPressed()`, which is setting "Canceled" result by default, so no guarantees that your RESULT_OK will be the real returning value.

I recommend to change code like:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Bundle counters = new Bundle();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    counters.putInt("Win", wins);
    counters.putInt("Loss", losses);
    counters.putInt("Draw", draws);
    i.putExtras(counters);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

Please let us know will it help or not.

Comment: I've been staring at this almost 2 days and didn't see that.  Thank you so much.  Ah, nuts.  Now "Bundle counts = data.getExtras();" is throwing an exception

Comment: OK, fixed the null point exception.  but I'm back to the original problem, it's not overwriting the original variable.  editing my original question to incorporate changes

Comment: Please see the updated answer. If it will not help - I'll ask you to paste your Fisrt Activity's onCreate() or other method, where plWin variable is changed

Comment: UPD:  made the change you suggested.  It didn't hurt anything, but didn't change the outcome either.

Comment: Alright... I've pasted the entirety of both activities... thanks so much for helping.  plWin, plLoss, and plDraw are all defined about the first activity's onCreate method

Comment: I GOT IT.  my 'startActivityForResult' had "RESULT_OK" in it rather than an int.  thanks so much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

You Mistake is at the position of request code you are writing resultcode (RESULT_OK)

```
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_OK); //incorrect
```

What I am suggesting make an static variable like this

```
public static final int REQUEST_SECOND=100;
```

and pass it like

```
statrtActivityForResult(i,REQUEST_SECOND);
```

then in the second activty make a static varible for result also

```
public static final int MY_RESULT=101;
```

and call the second activity

```
setResult(MY_RESULT);
```

and write onActivityResult Like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent i){

if(requestcod==REQUEST_SECOND){


    Bundle counts = i.getExtras();
    if (resultCode == MY_RESULT) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BOOM SHAKA LAKA!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        plWin = counts.getInt("Win", 100);
        plLoss = counts.getInt("Loss", 100);
        plDraw = counts.getInt("Draw", 100);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my 'startActivityForResult' had "RESULT_OK" in it rather than an int.

changing it from what's shown in OP to:

```
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

fixed it.

Thanks everybody for their contributions!